# Using Facebook/Gmail Login? Can I access profile details?

Tags: facebook, api

If i get someone to login to my website/mobileApp using Facebook can I access his profile details? How?

Comment: graphurl/me should give you the details. Plenty of examples on the net. Show some effort.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could. You only have to ask for permissions:

For example, for Facebook, using jQuery you could do that:

1- Create a app at facebook developers and get his id (http://developers.facebook.com/).

2- Call the facebook Javascript SDK:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
   window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
          appId: 'YOUR_APP_ID', 
          status: true, 
          cookie: true, 
          xfbml: true
      });
    };
</script>
```

3- Call the facebook login function:

```
<div id="myFbloginBt">Login with facebook</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#myFbloginBt").click(function(){
      loginFacebook();
   });
});


function loginFacebook(){

    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse){
            //Get logged user info
            FB.api('/me', function (response) {
                    alert(response.email);
            });
        }
        else{
            alert("Please accept the permissions");
        }
    }, { scope: 'email'});
}
</script>
```

Where scope are the thing that you want to access and need permission.
You could see all scope variables here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/#permissions